# Converting several columns of a data frame to different classes quickly

Tags: r, class, date, dataframe, posixct

I need to import a great deal of values from several .csv files. That, I have no issue with. However, the columns of the data frame that my function returns when importing said variables need to be converted to different classes.

This is what the data frame looks like:

[link to data frame (4'740'357 obs. of 6 variables)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SG5n8.png)

```
structure(list(start_date = c("2017-07-22 00:00", "2017-07-22 00:00", 
          "2017-07-22 00:00", "2017-07-22 00:00", "2017-07-22 00:00"), 
          start_station_code = c(6360L, 6248L, 6183L, 6248L, 6143L), 
          end_date = c("2017-07-22 00:13", "2017-07-22 00:10", "2017-07-22 00:13", 
          "2017-07-22 00:08", "2017-07-22 00:25"), 
          end_station_code = c(7046L, 6233L, 6234L, 6199L, 6270L), 
          duration_sec = c(807L, 642L, 774L, 529L, 1505L), 
          is_member = c(1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 1L)), 
          row.names = 584979:584983, class = "data.frame")
```

The `$start_date` and `$end_date` columns need to be converted to a Date class (or `POSIXct`, whichever is most convenient), and `$is_member` needs to be converted to a factor class.

So far, I manage to convert said columns with this code:

```
# data is the data frame. 

data[ , c(1,3)] <- lapply(data[ , c(1,3)], as.Date)
data$is_member <- as.factor(data$is_member)
```

However, completing the execution of my function can take up to three minutes. I was wondering if anyone had any idea as to how I could speed up this process. Take into consideration that my data frame will most likely have up to **5 million rows**.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Please read the info about [how to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and how to give a [reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example/5963610). This will make it much easier for others to help you.

Comment: The only way, I can think off for speeding up is using the [tag:data.table]-package. I.e.: `library(data.table); setDT(dat); dat[, c(1,3) := lapply(.SD, as.Date), .Sdcols = c(1,3)][, is_member := as.factor(is_member)]`

Comment: Consider using `read_csv` from the `readr` package (note the underscore instead of the dot) - this function enables you to state the classes in the call itself, and I believe is faster that the base function.

Comment: Similar to what @Jaap was getting at, my guess is that a not-insignificant portion of those three minutes can be copying the data around, whereas `data.table` tends to work in-place (much faster). In general, I'd think that comment would be your fastest unless you have the ability to fix it at read-in as @iod suggested. If you want more help, please provide *usable* data, not an image: it cannot be copied or searched (SEO), it breaks screen-readers, and it may not fit well on some mobile devices. Ref: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/3358272. Possibly with `data.frame(...random...)`.

Comment: @iod you can state the classes in the base read-functions as well with the `colClasses`-parameter ...... (see `?read.table`)

Comment: Thanks you all for the feedback! @iod I haven't mentionned that I'm subsetting my data frame because the main use of the function is importing data between to dates that the user imputs. So the conversion must be done after that, because that is when there will be the least amount of rows to work on. 

@Jaap I've looked into the link you sent me and added a reproduction of the data frame. Also, I'm not familiar with `data.table`, but I'll look into it at this instant.

Comment: Charles, I think stating the classes at the outset is probably going to beat any line-by-line change you choose to do later, regardless of the number of rows, because that doesn't require copying anything (every line needs to be assigned a class ANYWAY in the first read), so if at all possible, I'd advise you to do that.

Comment: @iod -- I stand corrected. My function is now down to 70 seconds as opposed to around 200 to import the same amount of data! Thanks alot!

Answer (score 0):

When importing data with read.csv, define the classes of your columns with the `colClasses` argument.

In my case, the solution was:

```
classCol <- c("Date", "factor", "Date", "factor" ,"numeric" , "factor")

# Data is the data frame

data <- rbind(data, read.csv(fileImport, stringsAsFactors = FALSE, 
        header = TRUE, colClasses = classCol ))
```

The credits for the solution go to @Jaap and @iod.